# Procura por palavras em quase 1 milhão de arquivos

Tags: c++, índices, sistema-de-arquivos

Estou procurando por métodos/ideias que possam me ajudar na solução do meu problema. Eu tenho uma estrutura de pastas / arquivos que meu programa gera, até aí tudo bem. Mas o que acontece é que essa pasta já contém mais de 900 mil arquivos. Cada arquivo desse é bem pequeno, cerca de 1 KB, tem um cabeçalho e um texto.

Atualmente a pesquisa usada pelo software é básica: realmente abre arquivo por arquivo e procura pela palavra. Mas imagine a demora da pesquisa... num SSD, pesquisar pela palavra `saude` me gerou uma espera de mais de 8 minutos.

Fiz alguns testes para ver se reduzir o número de arquivos ajudaria, mas notei que ajudaria pouco, ainda sim, a pesquisa demoraria minutos.

A ideia atualmente é (não utilizando qualquer banco de dados) indexar de forma manual, com um processo externo responsável por isto, palavras de 3 ou mais caracteres por pasta, diminuindo a pesquisa de milhões pra algumas milhares mas ainda sim poderia demorar alguns segundos em alguns casos.

Fiquei pensando também em como funciona a indexação do Windows para conteúdo do arquivo:

[[image: 1]]

Fiz alguns pequenos testes a respeito do "o que demora na pesquisa":

> Tempo para abrir os arquivos + ler: 465.948. Encontrados: 2921
>
> Tempo procurando                 : 264.318. Encontrados: 2921
>
> Tempo para abrir os arquivos + ler: 788.992. Encontrados: 2921
>
> Temp procurando                      : 599.093. Encontrados: 2921
>
> Tempo para abrir os arquivos + ler: 834.300. Encontrados: 2921
>
> Tempo procurando                 : 572.496. Encontrados: 2921
>
> Tempo para abrir os arquivos + ler: 709.464. Encontrados: 2921
>
> Tempo procurando                 : 539.053. Encontrados: 2921
>
> Tempo para abrir os arquivos + ler: 857.443. Encontrados: 2921
>
> Tempo procurando                 : 761,121. Encontrados: 2921
>
> Tempo para abrir os arquivos + ler: 909.440. Encontrados: 2921
>
> Tempo procurando                 : 602.000. Encontrados: 2921
>
> Tempo para abrir os arquivos + ler: 865.306. Encontrados: 2921
>
> Tempo procurando                 : 499.046. Encontrados: 2921

O teste foi feito em 1000 arquivos apenas. No primeiro resultado, leva em conta a abertura do arquivo, no segundo apenas o tempo em que ele está buscando algo (no meu teste usei `strstr`).

Existe algum método para deixar isto mais rápido sem usar banco de dados? Que não sei se resolveria o caso, já que em média teria 200 caracteres por arquivo onde seriam milhões de caracteres disponíveis para pesquisar. Se não for possível sem banco de dados, qual seria a ideia geral? Um banco de dados pode lidar bem com esse volume de dados?

Comment: onde está o código?

Comment: Já pensou em usar a API do Windows Search?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo bom, na verdade não, mas seria como ativar a opção de indexar conteúdos e fazer a procura por código na aplicação?

Comment: Isso, se não me falha a memória você abre uma conexão OleDB para o provider do search e faz a query como SQL mesmo

Comment: @LeandroAngelo. Vou ver isto, obrigado pela dica. Essa procura de minutos aí tá sendo um probleminha pra mim!

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/search/-search-3x-wds-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minha solução, como sugerido pelo Leandro Angelo nos comentários, foi usar a API do Windows Search.
Fiz a implementação do IFilter numa DLL e registrei para o mesmo ser usado.

Com isto, pude abrir uma conexão OleDB, criar propriedades novas e executar queries. Ficou rápido e muito bom.

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin Kouketsu, a melhor técnica a ser utilizada para esse cenário é o mecanismo full-text search. Existe um banco de dados relacional que tem esse recurso: PostgreSQL. Existe também o Solr e ElasticSearch, que incluem pesquisa de texto completo e, principalmente, indexação em tempo real como você mencionou acima; todos os dois últimos é baseado no projeto Lucene.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada a respeito desse mecanismo `full text search`. Vi que SQLite também tem e e SQLServer. SQL Server seria minha primeira opção porque na empresa já usamos softwares MS. Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: O Apache Solr (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/) é desenhado para sua solução man! Você terá boas surpresas com a utilização dessa ferramenta!